# I was trying to declare a function which takes a string as an input and give an int as an output

Tags: c, string, function, compiler-errors, cs50

my code is not identifying type string. I am using c to program

[image: []]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Aconcagua it is cs50 and it typedefs `string` as `char *`

Comment: @0___________ I see... Who on earth comes with such – well, just for politeness – questionable ideas, hiding pointer nature for no value and (worse) inhibiting constant strings the usual way (`string const` – which won't work as expected...)???

Comment: @Aconcagua - MIT

Comment: @0___________ Honestly, would expect better from them, just can shake heads.

Answer (score 2):

In your calls to `count_letter()`, `count_words()` and `count_scenteces()` you include a unnecessary `string` type in the function argument.

You should only include `string` when declaring a variable of some sort for example:

`string x = "hi";`

So to fix this problem replace each instance of `string text` in your function calls with `text`.

This will reference the `text` variable instead of inappropriately introducing a new variable of type `string` into the program.

Comment: `cs50.h` contains `typedef char* string;`.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter types are only put in function declarations, not function calls.

```
int letters = count_letters(string text);
```

should be

```
int letters = count_letters(text);
```